# Is there a way to use TypeScript to constrain string primitives to valid email strings?

Tags: typescript, string, function, class, types

Instead of using a string type that allows any string to be assigned to an Email variable like this:

```
type Email = string;
let email: Email;
email = "myEmail"; //INVALID EMAIL, BUT NO ERROR
```

Is there a type that can be used to constrain the Email variable to valid email strings only? So if an invalid email string is being assigned, it shows a type error. And if a valid email string is being assigned, there's no type error. Something like this:

```
type Email = ValidEmailString;
let email: Email;
email = "myEmail"; //ERROR, INVALID EMAIL
email = "myEmail@stackoverflow.com" //NO ERROR, VALID EMAIL
```

I know of a wrapper class that can somewhat implement this. This class can validate and store an email string, but the problem is that the class produces an object, and never produces a string primitive:

```
class Email {
  value: string;
  constructor( value:string ) {
    if ( isValidEmail(value) ) this.value = value;
    else throw new Error( "Invalid email" );
  }
}
let email: Email;
email = new Email( "myEmail" ); //ERROR, INVALID EMAIL
email = new Email( userInput ) //ERROR IF userInput IS INVALID EMAIL
email = new Email( "myEmail@stackoverflow.com" ); //NO ERROR, BUT AN OBJECT IS RETURNED
```

The class forces the email string to be accessed through the `value` property like this:

```
console.log( email.value ); //DISPLAYS "myEmail@stackoverflow.com"
console.log( email.value.includes("@") ); //DISPLAYS true
console.log( email.value == "myEmail@stackoverflow.com" ); //DISPLAYS true
```

Is there a way to use a type (and maybe a function) to validate email strings, preferably before compiling and during runtime? So that it would be possible to access the string directly and intuitively like this:

```
console.log( email ); //DISPLAYS "myEmail@stackoverflow.com"
console.log( email.includes("@") ); //DISPLAYS true
console.log( email == "myEmail@stackoverflow.com" ); //DISPLAYS true
```

Comment: There are too many cases to cover, maybe you want some fixed domains and .etc, but I can suggest something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N9Qp3N). Does it work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: How do you define a "valid email string"? That's the first question you need to answer. Without knowing what a "valid email string" even is, it is impossible to implement a type that checks for "valid email strings".

Comment: Thank you for wanting clarification. Regular expressions for email matching are easy to find. My concern is the type aspect.

Comment: Without an explicit definition of what a "valid email string" is then there's not enough information to answer your question properly, sorry. Nearly everyone agrees that there should be an "`@`" in there; after that there's much disagreement. And just saying there are regular expressions in existence doesn't really help: TS doesn't have regex-validated literals, so it would take work to try to translate a particular regex into a template literal type or type constraint. If it's just "make sure `@` appears", then [here you go](https://tsplay.dev/WPKxqm). If it's something else, what is it?

Comment: I will do so when I get a chance. It’s my bedtime now so I will get to it after I wake up.

Comment: @jcalz I like that answer. It works. And yes, "make sure @ appears" is fine. Please submit the answer and explain how it works. Some concerns - will an error be thrown if the Email variable is assigned an invalid value during runtime? If not, how can an invalid email be identified during runtime using your strategy?

Comment: What do you mean "during runtime"?  Where is the code written that makes such an assignment? If it's TS code then it will have a compile error when compiled and you don't need a runtime check. If it's out-of-band JS code then no error will happen, but *that's the same for all TS/JS*. If I write `let a: string = "abc"` and later "at runtime" someone assigns `a = 123`, then there will be no warning because TS isn't there. TS's type checking assumes TS code, not random JS code. Something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mAgjvw) might be useful for hybrid TS/JS situations. Should I write that up?

Comment: @jcalz You're right, I didn't mention runtime in my question. I apologize for the confusion.

The example class that I wrote included runtime checks only. I like your example because it included pre-compile checks. If the function you wrote were the same name as the type, and if the function accepted an `Email` parameter instead of a `string` parameter, the usage would look like the class I wrote, except "new" is not required:

`let email: Email;`
`email = Email( "myEmail" ); //PRE-COMPILE ERROR`
`email = Email( userInput ); //POSSIBLE RUNTIME ERROR`

Comment: My function as written would reject `Email(userInput)` (assuming `userInput` is of type `string`) since `userInput` is not known to be an `Email`.  If you want it to *accept* `string` but *reject* string literal types known not to be `Email`, then maybe [this version](//tsplay.dev/NlMgQm) is what you want?  If so then I'll write up an answer, but please also [edit] the question to explicitly state this is the behavior you're looking for, since these comments might and should get cleaned up.  Please also let me know whether or not I should write up an answer or if I'm still missing something.

Comment: @jcalz That's excellent. Your code finds pre-compile errors and runtime errors. That's what I call robust. I'll update the question.

Comment: I will write up an answer but I’m traveling so it might not be until sometime tomorrow

Comment: @jcalz Excellent. By the way, it appears that your code works even if `<T extends string>` is changed to `<T>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for a hybrid TypeScript/JavaScript approach to validating an email address.  First, we will define a "valid email address" as a string that contains the at-sign "`@`" character.  That's probably too loose (a string consisting of only `"@"` is unlikely to be "valid") but it's what we'll use.

---

In TypeScript's type system we can use a "pattern" [template literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) (as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#40598](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40598)) to represent such strings:

```
type Email = `${string}@${string}`;
let email: Email;
email = "myEmail"; // error, Type '"myEmail"' is not assignable to type '`${string}@${string}`'.
email = "myEmail@stackoverflow.com" // no error
```

But, like all of TypeScript's type system, this has no runtime effect, since types are [erased](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#erased-types) from the compiled JavaScript.

---

At runtime, you could write `email.includes("@")` as a check.  But this has no effect on how TypeScript views the typings.

---

So, let's take a hybrid approach.  We will write an `Email()` function which accepts a `string` and either returns an `Email` (if it's valid) or throws a runtime error (if it's not). However, you try to call the function with a string [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) that's known not to be a valid `Email`, you should *also* get a compile time error.

Here's how it could look:

```
function isValidEmail(x: string): x is Email {
    return x.includes("@")
}

function Email<T extends string>(x: T & (string extends T ? string : Email)): Email {
    if (!isValidEmail(x))
        throw new Error(`Error! "${x}" is not a valid email string`);
    return x;
}
```

The `isValidEmail()` function is a [custom type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) which we use to tell the compiler that `email.includes("@")` is a way to test if `email` is or is not an `Email`.  (The compiler is *not* able to analyze that `includes()` call in a way that relates it to the `Email` type, so we have to do it instead.)

The `Email()` function implementation merely calls `isValidEmail()` and throws if it returns `false`.  This lets the compiler understand that, if the function returns, it's returning an `Email`.  The tricky part is the call signature, which is of the form:

```
<T extends string>(x: T & (string extends T ? string : Email)) => Email
```

This is a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function with a type parameter `T`.  The compiler will infer `T` to be the type of the argument the function's called with.  By [constraining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `T` to `string` we give the compiler a hint that we want it to infer a string literal type for `T` if possible (this might not be *necessary*, but it's still probably a good idea).

Then, once the compiler infers `T`, we [intersect](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) it with the [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) `(string extends T ? string : Email)`:

If `T` is just `string`, then that evaluates to `string`, and so the input is `string & string` or just `string`, and no compiler error will happen.  If the string passed in has no "`@`" in it, then there will still be a runtime error.  But the compiler can't know.

On the other hand, if `T` is some string literal type narrower than `string`, then that conditional type evaluates to `Email`, and so the input is `T & Email`, which is equivalent to `T` if and only if `T` is a valid subtype of `Email`.  Otherwise it evaluates to `never` and there will be a compiler error.

---

Let's test it out:

```
email = Email("okay@example.com"); // okay with compiler and runtime

email = Email("oopsiedoodle"); // compiler error and runtime error


function getUserInput(): string {
    return "abc" + (Math.random() < 0.5 ? "@" : "") + "def";
}

email = Email(getUserInput()); // no compiler error, maybe a runtime error
```

So that gives all three major possibilities: the input is known at compile time to be a valid email (success both at compile and runtime), the input is known at compile time to be an *invalid* email (failure both at compile and runtime), or the input is only known to be `string` at compile time, (success at compile time and possibly success or failure at runtime).  Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6&ts=5.1.3#code/PTAEDMHsCdQBwK7QKagCoGUA0oAuALASwGdQTRiFxxCBjQ5AO1wFgAoXATzlQFEBbAIaEANqAC8oAAYASAN7Fc0QowDmAXwAC8xcrXqpAbnYjkuUMiGiAXKAHCRxtpYcTQAIn6d7o94dAgFtDQMDho3KgA5J7eViLukWSkjJDmgsTEhKqMggBGpniQeBGgkbIKSioa2hV6GlKRAHTsLqJuMT4imoqCtADWkABuyNDgIpAA7o20kPzuAWApQSHQ7Gts4AiMtLiEkIxJAGqCIoQAJp0AFAAetrpVAJS210l2caBy7KDfoCi4SAdro0VLQRAgzshiJd3Jp3A92Op1pttrt9m8HAAeNAWa64JhnUj3NQAPhutmxADJQJciaocXjGAT0KAAPwUSpqUC2ToPJ7otqfNg-MjgakAQhIx1OFziN15X2FPwIIQmoEYyFVvGCMEuUi1KzFHnk13U83IKTSoEGJ3OFnetKkDycwr+ANA1yciLYLXekiu7kgfUEnE0yGugn4cFM01mcP8gUDwdAE0IBFAM0johGoEEjN+W12-GQ7CUnA+Cu+rTEftlAcgcEyyDOkEgZ1McYW6dmcCzsBGKwR6cEuFo+GpyAe5aFPxmjGIkGj41UlwnnYI5BO89+yDgMFwpFzyxgCKRWx2ewOqjMAFViCMAJKMRC4S582lTl1mN3uPK0eYAampABZYd8EaaBc2bfhX1ADFQAABkaABWVkPFhLkPDhUBAPcCFwD8E9vWcX1+RES4r1wW8HyfBAX15eMwETMsUzTDMe1MaAcCEThclQQR82YQgiyPaAgA)

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation, especially about the conditional type in the Email function. Now I understand that TypeScript is looking at sets. `oopsiedoodle` is in a set with only 1 value, which is just `oopsiedoodle`. When `oopsiedoodle` is sent through the Email function, TypeScript determines with `extends` that the `string` set is not the same as the `oopsiedoodle` set. Then using `&`, the `oopsiedoodle` set is intersected with the `Email` set. Because those sets don't intersect, they result in `never`, which can be seen when hovering over the type error.

Answer (score 1):

You may use branded types

```
const brand /* : unique symbol */ = Symbol()
type brand = typeof brand;
type Branded<T, B> = T & {[K in brand]: B}

type email = Branded<string, 'email'>

function isEmail(maybeEmail: string): maybeEmail is email {
    return maybeEmail.includes('@')
}
function assertIsEmail(maybeEmail: string): email {
    if (!isEmail(maybeEmail)) throw new Error('not email');
    return maybeEmail;
}

let a /* : email */ = assertIsEmail('foo@bar.com')

a = 'string' // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'email'.
let s: string = a; // ok

a = assertIsEmail('string') // runtime Error('not email')

a.slice(2, 6) // 'o@ba'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's in the right direction of what I'm looking for, but something doesn't look right about the branding. Also, why are there imports?

Comment: typo (forgot to remove them)

Comment: "something doesn't look right about the branding" there are like 5 different ways of branding, mainly for if you can assign `string` to `Branded<string, B>` (- by making '[brand]?:' which you don't want afaik) and if you can mix brands like `Branded<T, A|B> === Branded<T, A> & Branded<T, B>` (made by making `[brand]: Record<B, true>`)

Comment: I generally name branded versions of simple types (like `string`) in camelCase (like `email`) to mark them being non-objects